# SQL LEFT JOIN combined with regular joins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, left-join

I have the following query that joins a bunch of tables.

I'd like to get every record from the INDUSTRY table that has consolidated_industry_id = 1 regardless of whether or not it matches the other tables.  I believe this needs to be done with a LEFT JOIN?

```
SELECT attr.industry_id        AS option_id,
       attr.industry           AS option_name,
       uj.ft_job_industry_id,
       Avg(CASE
             WHEN s.salary > 0 THEN s.salary
           END)                AS average,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN s.salary > 0 THEN attr.industry
             END)              AS count_non_zero,
       Count(attr.industry_id) AS count_total
FROM   industry attr,
       user_job_ft_job uj,
       salary_ft_job s,
       user_job_ft_job ut,
       [user] u,
       user_education_mba_school mba
WHERE  u.user_id = uj.user_id
       AND u.user_id = ut.user_id
       AND u.user_id = mba.user_id
       AND uj.ft_job_industry_id = attr.industry_id
       AND uj.user_job_ft_job_id = s.user_job_id
       AND u.include_in_student_site_results = 1
       AND u.site_instance_id IN ( 1 )
       AND uj.job_type_id = 1
       AND attr.consolidated_industry_id = 1
       AND mba.mba_graduation_year_id NOT IN ( 8, 9 )
       AND uj.admin_approved = 1
GROUP  BY attr.industry_id,
          attr.industry,
          uj.ft_job_industry_id
```

This returns only one row, but there are 8 matches in the industry table where consolidated_industry_id = 1.

--- EDIT: The real question here is, how do I combine the LEFT JOIN with the regular joins?

Comment: Start by writing the regular joins as ANSI joins...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `left join` for tables that may miss a corresponding record. Put the conditions for each table in the `on` clause of the `join`, not in the `where`, as that would in effect make them inner joins anyway. Something like:

```
select
  attr.industry_id AS option_id, attr.industry AS option_name,
  uj.ft_job_industry_id, AVG(CASE WHEN s.salary > 0 THEN s.salary END) AS average, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN s.salary > 0 THEN attr.industry END) as count_non_zero,
  COUNT(attr.industry_id) as count_total 
from
  industry attr
  left join user_job_ft_job uj on uj.ft_job_industry_id = attr.industry_id and uj.job_type_id = 1 and uj.admin_approved = 1
  left join salary_ft_job s on uj.user_job_ft_job_id = s.user_job_id 
  left join [user] u on u.user_id = uj.user_id and u.include_in_student_site_results = 1 and u.site_instance_id IN (1)
  left join user_job_ft_job ut on u.user_id = ut.user_id
  left join user_education_mba_school mba on u.user_id = mba.user_id and mba.mba_graduation_year_id not in (8, 9)
where
  attr.consolidated_industry_id = 1 
group by
  attr.industry_id, attr.industry, uj.ft_job_industry_id
```

If you have any tables that you know always have a corresponding record, just use `innser join` for that.

Comment: Thanks for the very prompt response.  I'm getting an incorrect syntax on the WHERE clause there.  Thoughts?

Comment: @AdamLevitt: It was the `on` clause that was missing on the `user_job_ft_job` join. I rearranged the joins in the code above.